# Getting missing dependency error with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the classic "Module 'ngLocale' error is not available" error when angular tries to load up my module.  I can't for the life of me figure out what dependency I am missing.  Here's my app.js:

```
(function() {
    var app, dependencies;

    dependencies = ["ngRoute"];

    app = angular.module('myapp', dependencies);

    app.run(['$location', '$rootScope'], function($location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });
    });

    app.config(['$routeProvider'], function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Content/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            title: 'Home'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
}).call(this);
```

My javascript files are loaded correctly in order.  What am I missing?

Comment: Angularjs $route is in a separate file do you have it loaded?

Comment: Yes, angular-route.js gets loaded after angular.js but before this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to include the function in the array:

```
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });
}]);
```

and:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Content/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        title: 'Home'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: D'oh - it's always the little things.  Thanks!